# Kill network connection in the middle of the test using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, networking

I'm trying to kill my network in the middle of a test. and when I kill the network, the system should prompt a dialog saying network is gone. When I do this manually, I get the dialog. And I used the following code,

```html
public void exitBrowserTab() throws IOException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url");

        driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signin-button")).click();


        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("offline", true);
        map.put("latency", 5);
        map.put("download_throughput", 500);
        map.put("upload_throughput", 1024);

        CommandExecutor executor = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getCommandExecutor();
        Response response = executor.execute(new Command(((ChromeDriver)driver).getSessionId(), "setNetworkConditions", ImmutableMap.of("network_conditions", ImmutableMap.copyOf(map))));



    }
```

When I run this code, it won't give me that dialog. but, when I refresh the page, it tells me that there's no network.

What did I do wrong?

Manual Steps -

1. Go to the url
2. Successful login
3. Network drop
4. Dialog appears

Comment: Can you update the question with the manual steps to repro the behavior?

Comment: Is it possible to kill the proxy using selenium?

Comment: _Network drop_: Isn't `put("offline", true)` enough to drop the network, which sounds good as disconnecting the network manually?

Comment: hmm, do you have a better way?

Comment: I'm trying to get hold of an application to repro _`there's no network`_ or _`network is gone`_

Comment: Can you share URL or any other website URL which behaves similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could turn of internet using the bash command,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig /release");
```

and turn it back on using,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig /renew");
```

This will automatically turn off your wifi and turn it on again.